# How to add File->Save to Cloud... and Cell->Cell Properties to my customized toolbar?

Tags: front-end, palettes, docked-cell, toolbar

I'm programming my own `DockedCells` toolbar. Everything happened ok, the only things beyond my ability to resolve are: (1) adding a button (or an `ActionMenu` action) that works as an equivalent of the File->Save to Cloud... which opens the Save to Wolfram Cloud dialog window, and (2) adding `ActionMenu` actions that works as equivalents of the Cell->Cell Properties togglers (Open, Editable, ...); on/off indicators would be great but not necessary. I browsed here some hours and it seems to me that no FrontEnd tokens are available for these actions. Is there anybody to help with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Currently I'm using Mathematica 14.0.0.

Comment: Save to Cloud: `NotebookOpen[FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "Components", "CloudDialogs", "FrontEnd", "SystemResources", "WolframCloudSaveDialog.nb"}]]`

Comment: @Domen, awesome, thank you very much!